# ELL Mod asks: Are these types of questions good candidates for migration here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope, migration

I'm one of the Mods at [SE.ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com).

Our site attracts a fair number of questions asking for learning resource and technique recommendations. We've decided that these requests are off-topic for the main site. We didn't want to simply close/delete these questions, so we made the compromise to allow them on our Meta site, and have been migrating them ever since.

I'm not a fan of this because Meta is for questions about the main site itself, not normal questions that happen to be parallel to the main site's focus.

So I'm hoping SE.LL is a good place to migrate them.

Before I start that discussion at ELL, I want to make sure those migrations won't just get closed and sent back to us, so I'd like to get this community's opinion on a few recent requests we've received. Do these fit here? If they were migrated here, would they get closed for anything other than being a dupe?

Thanks for the help!

[Can you suggest any AI based voice chat robot (such as some website) to practice spoken English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/can-you-suggest-any-ai-based-voice-chat-robot-such-as-some-website-to-practice)?

[Strategies for Improving Understanding of Indian English Accent](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/strategies-for-improving-understanding-of-indian-english-accent)

[What's a Good Grammar Textbook?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/whats-a-good-grammar-textbook)

[How can I learn Indian English?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5951/how-can-i-learn-indian-english)

[Online collocation dictionaries and English corpus search resources](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/online-collocation-dictionaries-and-english-corpus-search-resources)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ELL.SE's rules, but for the listed questions:

- [Can you suggest any AI based voice chat robot (such as some website) to practice spoken English](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5940/can-you-suggest-any-ai-based-voice-chat-robot-such-as-some-website-to-practice)?

  Looks on-topic here to me.  It'd be better off phrased less as a "suggestion" and more of a "what's available" or "what's popular".
- [Strategies for Improving Understanding of Indian English Accent](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5957/strategies-for-improving-understanding-of-indian-english-accent)

  Definitely on topic here.
- [What's a Good Grammar Textbook?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5955/whats-a-good-grammar-textbook)

  It's a bit too opinionated, but I'd still lean towards on-topic here.  It could be better phrased as "What makes a good English-grammar textbook?" or "What are the well-received English-grammar textbooks?"
- [How can I learn Indian English?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5951/how-can-i-learn-indian-english)

  On topic here, but would benefit from being more specific.
- [Online collocation dictionaries and English corpus search resources](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5891/online-collocation-dictionaries-and-english-corpus-search-resources)

  Definitely on topic here.

Basically, it's quite appropriate to migrate the above questions to LanguageLearning.SE.  Some of these questions hit multiple categories on the [on-topic page](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which I highlight below:

> Questions on the following topics are welcome here:
>
> - **Questions about learning or teaching techniques regarding any human language**, including dead, unspoken and constructed languages.
> - **Questions regarding definite obstacles faced by anyone learning a language**.
> - **Questions regarding specific language learning techniques or resources, and their effectiveness in comparison to others**.
> - Requests seeking books, studies, web sites, or other resources supporting the scientific basis for any aspect of language study.
> - **Questions seeking hard-to-find learning resources for a specific language**. Be as specific as possible.
> - **Questions regarding the use of language-learning or teaching software or technology** (i.e. Duolingo, Anki, etc.) in conjunction with the learning/teaching process.

(PS. Chinese.SE made a community wiki list of Mandarin resources: [Resources for learning Mandarin Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/resources-for-learning-mandarin-chinese), and we can close questions answered in that post as duplicates.  Maybe this is an option for ELL?)

Comment: Thanks Rebecca. We were mostly expecting "no"s, so this is good news. As things progress with the ELL end of the conversation, I'll ping you here. Not sure how soon it'll be, but it's in the pipe. ELL does have a list of such resources, and the maintenance and location of that list would be part of the discussion.